# CE 1.8.1 display taxes differently per customer group

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, tax, configuration

And next question popping up.

In our store we have a sales tax rule of 19%, we have two customer groups, B2C and B2B. The former shall see the prices only including taxes (law in Germany), while the B2B customers have a special interest in seeing the prices excluding taxes.

The calculation of the tax is the same for both, in fact it is the same tax, I just need to set the display taxes setting separetely for each customer group. But I only find general settings in system->configure->sales->taxes-> for displaying taxes for products and cart

Is there a way to configure this cleanly or do I have to use workarounds with tax rules or template rewrites?

Answer (score 1):

The Solution I finally came up with was to create a second website within the store management instead of a store view. This way you've got a bit more work managing two sites, but you can set different tax display settings for each website.
You have to make sure to activate all products, CMS and so on for both websites.